Azure Static Web App: Reported as Unsafe by
I implemented a sample Blazor WASM Static Web App with Api Functions.
This works locally and also when published, however when published it first comes up as a red page with the text "This site has been reported as unsafe
What must I do differently so that my app still works but is not reported as unsafe?
I did not try and steal any information etc?
Hosted by myapp-9999.5.azurestaticapps.net
Microsoft recommends you don’t continue to this site. It has been reported to Microsoft for containing misleading content that could lead you to lose personal info, financial data, and even money."
